# Extjs CheckboxModel - Checkonly not working in grid.plugin.CellEditing

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid, extjs4.1

I have grid panel with CheckboxModel  in **http://jsfiddle.net/Zsby6/**

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        checkOnly: true,
        mode: 'MULTI'
    }),
```

I have option `checkOnly: true` that mean **rows can only be selected by clicking on the checkbox column.**

But when i click checkall like

[image]

and then i click **Lisa** then 'allchecked' change to 'uncheck' and only select this row like

[image]

I want when i click a cell in Name column then all checkbox will not impact. How to do that? Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **checkOnly** config works only for **Extjs 3.x** version.
You can try this approach  :

```
listeners: {
        cellclick: function (sender, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
            clickedColIndex = cellIndex;
        },
        beforedeselect: function (rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
           return (clickedColIndex == 0);
        }
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/Zsby6/7/)

Comment: First time, when i click cell in name column -> row selected (i think not selected here) then i click checkall and i can't re-checkall :(

Comment: +1 for the solution. PS: `checkOnly` works also in Ext 4(2.2), but not in association with the `CellEditing` plugin.